# MySQL if exists update values else insert

Tags: php, mysql, sql, if-statement, exists

I am creating an application that stores a students attendance.

I am creating the database that will store this attendance and I am stuck on the mySQL query.

I want the query to search for the 'lecture name' and the 'user_id' (foreign key from other database) and if that exists increment the students attendance to the lecture (attended++ and total++)

So far I have this:

```
    INSERT INTO `attendance`(`attendance_id`, `module_code`, `lecture_name`, 
`attended`, `total`, `user_id`) VALUES ("null","test","TEST",1,1,1)
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
 attended = attended+1,total = total+1
```

This will insert a new row but for the ON DUPLICATE, there is no way to pass the primary key in to check for a 'duplicate'

I was wondering if there is another way to do this in MySQL other than ON DUPLICATE KEY, or if anyone can help me out.

Here is a screenshot of the database. For example see the 'Operations Research' was created when it should of incrememented the values. This is because I have no way of adding the primary key into the SQL query.

I would appreciate any help towards this,
Thanks.

[image: screenshot of the database]

Comment: What is your issue?

Comment: You don't need the primary key, any unique index will trigger `ON DUPLICATE KEY`. You should probably have a unique index on `(module_code, lecture_name, user_id)`

Answer (score 1):

The use of `null` in double quotes is troubling.  So, I think you should write the query as:

```
INSERT INTO `attendance`(`module_code`, `lecture_name`, `attended`, `total`, `user_id`)
    VALUES ('test', 'TEST', 1, 1, 1)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE attended = attended + 1, total = total + 1 ;
```

For this to work, you seem to want a unique index on `(lecture_name, user_id)`.

Your data model does seem suspicious because the table is repeating `lecture_name` on multiple rows.  It seems to me that you would want a `lectures` table and to use `lecture_id` in this table.

Comment: I suspect `module_code` should also be in the unique index.